# Can I save the buffer or contents of a console window for future use?

Tags: c#, winapi, input, console

I am having fun with Console Applications and just wanted to know. What's the best way to save the current buffer of a console window for later use and provide a sort of history navigation function. I know the Diagnostics namespace provides ability to read standard output but that's only if you redirect it, so basically you will have to run process all your results in a new window which seems a little dumb.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to read the console screen buffer.

I wrote a series of articles about accessing the Console API from .NET a few years ago. The article you're interested in is [Working with Console Screen Buffers](http://www.devsource.com/c/a/Using-VS/Working-with-Console-Screen-Buffers-in-NET/).

Full source code is available at http://mischel.com/pubs/consoledotnet/consoledotnet.zip.

Comment: @opatachibueze: Glad you found it useful. That's why I published it . . .

Comment: @JimMischel I'm interested in using your ConsoleDotNet project in something I'm working on. I have one question: what is the license for the project. I've got the source, but I don't see a copyright notice or license anywhere. (here's to hoping that it's MIT)

(sorry to bug you on SO, but I couldn't find any contact info on your blog or anywhere else on the internets for that matter)

Comment: @fre0n: MIT License. You should have checked my SO profile for my email address. Contact me there if you need more info.

Comment: @JimMischel It looks like email addresses aren't publicly visible on Stack Exchange sites. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77454/158214

Comment: @fre0n: My email address is on my home page. See "Contact" on www.mischel.com